# C++, Copy Constructor is not working properly in character arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, copy

This is the code, I made a class which contains the object of another class. I get the wrong output i.e garbage value.. i cant figure out whats is the problem.

Highlighted Line,s output gives garbage value but there is no error in compilation.. ive been using MS Visual Studio 2010

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class Address
{
char *street_no,*house_no,*city,*code;

public:

    **Address(Address &obj)
{

    int size;
    cout<<obj.street_no;
    size=strlen(obj.street_no);

    street_no=new char[size+1];
    strcpy(street_no,obj.street_no);

    size=strlen(obj.house_no);
    house_no=new char[size+1];
    strcpy(house_no,obj.house_no);
    size=strlen(obj.city);
    city=new char[size+1];
    strcpy(city,obj.city);
    size=strlen(obj.code);
    code=new char[size+1];
    strcpy(code,obj.code);

}**
Address()
{
    street_no=new char;
    house_no=new char;
    city=new char;
    code=new char;

}
~Address()
{
    delete street_no;
    delete house_no;
    delete city;
    delete code;
}

void set()
{
    cout<<"Enter Street Number : ";
    cin>>street_no;
    cout<<"Enter House Number : ";
    cin>>house_no;
    cout<<"Enter City : ";
    cin>>city;
    cout<<"Enter Code : ";
    cin>>code;
}
void get()
{

    cout<<"\nStreet Number : "<<street_no;
    cout<<"\nHouse Number : "<<house_no;
    cout<<"\nCity : "<<city;
    cout<<"\nCode : "<<code;

}



};

class person
{
Address obj;

public:
person()
{
}
person(person &one)
{
    Address::Address(one.obj);
}

void set()
{
    obj.set();
}

void get()
{
    obj.get();
}
~person()
{
exit(0);
}
};
int main()
{ 
person A;
A.set();
A.get();
**
person B(A);
    B.get();
**
getch();
}
```

Comment: Why did you include <string> if you are allocating memory manually ? You should take advantage of std::string unless this is an homework and you are forced to do it this way.

Comment: Use the c++ string, modify your code and tell us what errors you're getting. Secondly, your constructor is not doing anything "special". You may as well have done the `new char`'s from within the `set` function. Change your constructor to take street_no, house_no, city, code as parameters. You really shouldn't be doing I/O from within the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
Address()
{
    street_no=new char;
    house_no=new char;
    city=new char;
    code=new char;

}
```

This is where your first problem starts.  When you use the default constructor, you are creating pointers to a single `char`.  When you attempt to copy the object, you are going to get junk since `strlen` is going to look for a `\0` character to determine the length (and unless your `char` is just '\0', you are going to go off in the weeds of UB).  This will also be the case with your `get` and `set` functions as they attempt to write out a `char*` (but are actually expecting an array with a terminating null character), and read in a `char*` (same expectation), but you are only giving them 1 character to write.  In other words, you are going to invoke UB all over the place with what you have written.

```
~Address()
{
    delete street_no;
    delete house_no;
    delete city;
    delete code;
}
```

This will work fine for your default constructor (as written), but will not be correct for your copy-constructor.  Once you fix your default constructor, this will be incorrect for both.  When you create a new array (`new[]`), you must free the memory with `delete[]`.

This whole issue can be fixed by using `std::string` instead of trying to manage dynamic arrays yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ use the class 'string', instead of char*. You dont need to manage memory then. So replace

```
char *street_no,*house_no,*city,*code;
```

with 
    string street_no,house_no,city,code;